# ARM (M1) Image of Android Automotive

Tags: android, apple-m1, android-automotive

Do you know whether Google announced if they will make an ARM Android Automotive image available soon?

Currently its not available and therefore, as far as I understand, its not possible for me to develop using an Android Automotive emulator on my MBP M1. Even with Parallels and Windows it would not work right, because the hardware is still an ARM processor and I can only run an Windows ARM image in Parallels.

Thanks for your hints! :)

Greetings from Bavaria

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on my MBP M1. Did you get the Android Automotive OS emulator up and running?

Answer (score 2):

An ARM v8a emulator image for API level 32 compatible with Apple M1 and M2 chips is now available via the Android Studio [beta channel](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview#change_your_update_channel)! If you have one of the [Android Studio Preview versions](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview) (currently Dolphin or Electric Eel) installed alongside a stable Android Studio version, the image should be available there as those versions use the beta and canary update channels, respectively.

Comment: I have Dolphin 2021.3.1 RC1, but I cannot find automotive ARM v8a emulator image.

Comment: Okay, It is only in Android Studio "Preview" version, Dolphin Release Candidate doesn't have that image!